# Is there any way such that javascript can read files with custom extensions?

Tags: javascript

Let consider a custom extension **.cst**, and we have a javascript function **CSTReader()** especially designed to read **.cst** files. Here is an example :

files.cst :

```
I am a cst file. I have data in me such that I am readable by javascript.
```

index.js :

```
 document.write("Reqd Output : " +  CSTReader("files.cst") );
```

Output :

```
Reqd Output : I am a cst file. I have data in me such that I am readable by javascript.
```

So, can the **CSTReader()** be made ? Or it is not possible in javascript ? If no, any alternative to do so ? Or is it just waste of time ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can load any file with [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader). How readable the contents of the file are depend on what it is.

Comment: Local file on the client, or file on the web server? Reading the latter would mean a run-of-the-mill AJAX request, nothing special about that in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FileReader` object to do so. It will work on custom extension too.
Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader for documentation.

If your file contain plain text, you can use the `readAsText` method.

In your example, you can do something like:

```html
<input type="file" onchange="readFile"/> // put your file here
<script lang="js">

function readFile(e) {
  let file = e.target.files[0] // get the file

  let fileReader = new FileReader(); // instanciate Filereader
  fileReader.onloadend = function () { // bind your function to the onloadend method. It will be executed once the file is read.
    console.log(filereader.result);
    // do whatever you want with the content
  }; 
  fileReader.readAsText(file); // read the file, whatever the extension is.
}
</script>
```

You can also have a look at [this](https://www.javascripture.com/FileReader) demo.

Good luck

Comment: To load a file from a URL, you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of FileReader.